# PHP : Trouble developing CURL request for file upload to API

Tags: php, api, curl, file-upload, google-streetview-publish

I am having this problem from last few days to develop a CURL request in php to post file data to an API.

Here is the CURL request

```
$ curl --request POST \
    --url 'UPLOAD_URL' \
    --upload-file 'PATH_TO_FILE' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

for PATH_TO_FILE I have tried each and every method published over the web and stackoverflow too.

here is my PHP code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$sheader = array('Authorization: Bearer '.$_SESSION['access_token']);
$filename = $_FILES['upload-file']['name'];
$filedata = $_FILES['upload-file']['tmp_name'];
$filesize = $_FILES['upload-file']['size'];
$filetype = $_FILES['upload-file']['type'];

if($filename != '')
{
 $ch = curl_init();
 $cFile = new CURLFile(realpath($filename), $filetype, 'harish.jpg');
 //$cFile = '@'. realpath($filename);
 $data = array('upload-file' => $cFile); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cFile);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, realpath($filename));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_POST['upload_url']);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $sheader);
 curl_exec($ch);
 echo json_encode($ch);
 //echo json_encode(array('filename'=>$filename, 'temp_path'=>$filedata, 'basepath'=>realpath($filename)));

 } else {
    echo 'There is no file selected';
 }
```

Mostly the solution i have found on the web are these two mentioned below

Method 1 (for php < 5.5)

```
'@'.$filepath
```

Method 2 (for php > 5.5)

```
CURLFile($filename, $filetype, 'somefile.jpg');
```

or

```
curl_file_create($filedata, 'image/jpeg', $filename);
```

None of the above worked for me. I have use realpath($filename) too inside CURLFile to fetch absolute path of the file, but sadly that also not worked.

Comment: Have you tried the data-binary option?

Comment: @UmashankarDas I think yes i have tried once with data-binary also. But i can try once more if you suggest the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408904/send-post-request-with-data-specified-in-file-via-curl

Comment: Yes i have tried this before but not worked @UmashankarDas

Comment: Are you trying both methods because you don't know what your PHP version is? You can determine it rather easily if you call the `phpinfo()` function.

Comment: got the solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085110/upload-pano-image-using-street-view-publish-api/44669286#44669286
upload request is working with the php exec() function. Alvaro Gonzalez method is also right. But will not work here. Reason don't know

Answer (score 1):

I admit that [`CURLFile` documentation](http://php.net/CURLFile) is slightly ambiguous but the first constructor argument, `$name`, is in fact the physical path to the actual file you want to send, not the "friendly" name (which goes in the optional third argument, `$postname`). You should note there's something wrong since you never tell Curl about `$_FILES['upload-file']['tmp_name']`—it has no way to know what file you want to send.

So:

```
$filename = $_FILES['upload-file']['name'];
$filedata = $_FILES['upload-file']['tmp_name'];
$filesize = $_FILES['upload-file']['size'];
$filetype = $_FILES['upload-file']['type'];

$cFile = new CURLFile($filedata, $filetype, 'harish.jpg')
```

You aren't being notified about this because you're skipping error checking. You don't check the return value of any function, neither call [curl_error()](http://php.net/curl_error) anywhere in your code.

One more error you have is that you pass the `CURLFile` instance this way:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cFile);
```

Correct syntax should be like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['give_a_nice_post_name_here' => $cFile]);
```

Comment: Sorry i did n't mentioned error debugging code here. I have that on my code 
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
     $msg = curl_error($ch);
     $return = array('errmsg' => $msg);
  echo json_encode($return);
 }

Comment: I'm not good reading code in comments but I guess it's good. Curl is some times not very informative about errors. I've edited my answer.

Comment: yes i have pass that argument too. See in my question $data = array('upload-file' => $cFile);

I have tested with this too : curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);